# C code, seems to be skipping if statements

Tags: c, if-statement, skip

First and foremost, I am not asking anyone to write a program for me or to do my homework for me... I have an error and I can't figure out what's causing it, and where to look to fix it.

So I'm attempting to create a program that will take a command and an input file from the command line, and, based on the command selection, perform one of several functions: either coutn the lines of the input file, count the words of the input file, or check the input file for palindromes and then compare the palindromes (if any) to a dictionary file.

Here is the code as it stands:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void usage(char *prog_name) //usage file if input format is wrong
{
    printf("Usage: %s, <-h>|<-l>|<-w>|<-p>, <filename>\n", prog_name);
    exit(0);
}

void help(char *prog_name, char *filename) //help file for -h option
{
    printf("Welcome to the help file\n");
    printf("For number of lines, enter: <%s>, <-l>, <%s>.\n", prog_name, filename);
    printf("For number of words, enter: <%s>, <-w>, <%s>.\n", prog_name, filename);
    printf("To list the palindromes in alphabetical order, print the number of
    palindromes, and to check them against the dictionary, enter: <%s>, <-p>, <%s>\n",
    prog_name, filename);
    exit(0);
}

void fatal(char *);  //function for fatal errors
void *ec_malloc(unsigned int);  //error-checked malloc wrapper

void linecount(char *filename)  // counts the number of lines of input file
{
    char *infile;
    infile = (char *) ec_malloc(strlen(filename));
    strcpy(infile, filename);
    FILE *fp = fopen(infile, "r");

    if (fp == NULL)         
         fatal("input file does not exist");

    int ch;
    int count = 0;                                  

    do {             
    ch = fgetc(fp);
    if( ch== '\n')
            count++;
    }   
    while( ch != EOF );                                 

    printf("Total number of lines %d\n",count);
    exit(0);            
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3) //if there aren't enough arguments, display the usage file
    {
            usage(argv[0]);
    }
    else if (argv[1] == "-h") //this is the help option
    {
        help(argv[0], argv[2]);
    }
    else if (argv[1] == "-l") //this is the line count option
    {
        linecount(argv[2]);
    }
    else
    {

            fatal("skipped if functions");
    }
    return 0;
}
void fatal(char *message) //this function displays an error message and then exits
{   
    char error_message[100];
    strcpy(error_message, "[!!] Fatal Error ");
    strncat(error_message, message, 83);
    perror(error_message);
    exit(-1);
}

void *ec_malloc(unsigned int size) //wrapper function for an error checked malloc
{
    void *ptr;
    ptr = malloc(size);

    if(ptr == NULL)
        fatal("in ec_malloc() on memory allocation");

    return ptr;
}
```

So, when I run:

```
gcc -o fr filereader.c

./fr -h fevbwervrwe.txt
```

I get the error message stating that the if statements were skipped.

Same if I try running

```
./fr -l vrweqvervvq.txt
```

It seems the compiler is skipping over my if statements, and I honestly can't figure out why. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should put some printf to check the values of argc, argv[1], … Or use a debugger.

Comment: Try changing the if comparisons from argv[1] == "-h" to !strcmp(argv[1], "-h"). My C is a bit rusty but I don't think you can do that comparison with the == operator.

Comment: Obviously, you didn't step through your code in a debugger.  If you had, that would reveal the problem immediately.  Use of a debugger and code-stepping is NOT optional.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933614/c-string-using-equality-operator-for-comparing-two-strings-for-equality

Comment: Your symptoms, and your test, do not suggest a "skipping" of if statements; it suggests that the test conditions evaluate as false.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `strcmp()` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 6):

```
if (argv[1] == "-h")
```

This statement compares two pointers, not two strings. Try:

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "-h") == 0)
```

Answer (score 5):

In C, you need to compare string values using functions like

```
strcmp(str1, str2);
```

Don't compare string values using the `==` operator; which checks something completely different.

Answer (score 3):

Compile with "gcc -g -o fr filereader.c", and step through under the debugger (e.g. gdb).

I assure you the compiler isn't "ignoring" your "if" statements.

Do NOT use "argv[1] == "-h".  Use "if (strcmp (argv[1], "-h") == 0" instead...

Answer (score 2):

In C you don't compare strings with the `==` operator. Instead you use the following idiom:

```
if (strcmp(s1, s2) == 0) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, just understand that "argv[1]" == "-h" would mean you are comparing pointers. Keep this in mind.

And another suggestion I have for you is to look at `getopt()`. This is used to parse command line arguments in unix, and will make your life easier and help you in writing robust code.

Answer (score 1):

Try strcmp() instead of ==
as == compares the address where string values are stored
But strcmp compares the content (string values) which is required i think

e.g.
int main(){char *a="anshul";char *b="anshul";if(a==b){ printf("ok");} /*comapres address where anshul is stored*/ if(strcmp(a,b)){printf("ok"); /* this will compare values i.e string anshul therefore always equal but in previous case it depends whether both anshul stored on same memory or not
so not a advisable thing to do