# Parsing arguments from main C++

Tags: c++, program-entry-point, argv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C String — Using Equality Operator == for comparing two strings for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933614/c-string-using-equality-operator-for-comparing-two-strings-for-equality)

Basic question here. I'm compiling this program in g++ and running it with a single -r argument, (./a.out -r) however it does not output the specified cout statement below. Is there anything wrong with this code?

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    if (argv[1] == "-r" ) {
        cout << "First arg is -r" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot compare string literals using `==`, because what that does is compare *pointers* (i.e., memory addresses, which in this case are always going to be different).

Use [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) or compare [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) objects instead:

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "-r") == 0) { ... }
```

or

```
if (std::string(argv[1]) == "-r") { ... }
```

Comment: This is C++ though, not C. Can I still use strcmp?

Comment: @thisiscrazy4: That's because you tagged the question as C++. You can still use `strcmp` in C.

Comment: Yes it's C++, that's what I meant.

Comment: @thisiscrazy4: Ah, my mistake, sorry. Yes, both options are available in C++.

Comment: Ok that works fine in g++. However I get thread exceptions when compiling in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare string literals with ==. Use strcmp.

(Also, don't forget to check that argc is at least 2).

Answer (score 1):

One mistake in your code is you are comparing the address of the char array instead of comparing the values in the array. As people have said you can do it the `C` way using `strcmp` (although it's safer to use `strncmp` to avoid buffer overruns).

However, it's easier to use `std::string` in C++.

I would copy the args into a vector of strings.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<string> args(argv, argv+argc);
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would do something along these lines:

```
while (--argc && **++argv=='-')
{
   char *p;
    p=*argv+1;
    switch(tolower(*p))
    {
        case 'r':                                       
            break;

    }
}
```

basically, while there are some args left, check that there is a '-' char, then switch on the next char to see the modifier ('r', or 'a' etc)