# If statement is not evaluating correctly

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, argv

I am working on a console project and I just can't get this part to work.

```
void execute(char* argv[]) {
    char* printex = "print";
    if (argv[1] == printex) {
        print(argv);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Unknown function." << endl;
    }
}
```

Every time I type in "print" for `argv[1]`, it thinks I have typed in something else. I tried putting in

```
cout << argv[1];
```

and the output was print. Why is it not working then?

Comment: You're comparing pointers, not the arrays they point to.

Comment: Try defining `printex` as: `std::string printex = "print";` instead.

Comment: [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933614/c-string-using-equality-operator-for-comparing-two-strings-for-equality)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argv[1]` is a `char*`, so is `printex`. Comparing them will compare the address they contain, not the actual string. So they will never be same. You can use `std::string` (which is safer), or in the current form, use `strcmp` for comparison.

```
if( strcmp( argv[1], printex) == 0 )
 //mathced
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `if (argv[1] == printex)` with `if (strcmp(argv[1], printex)==0)` to compare strings (not pointers on strings).