# Equality check doesn't work as expected

Tags: c, string

As you can see at followed sample, I am comparing words those inside lyric variable and I want to get count's unique word but result returns `0`. Although there are 3 similar words as you can see in result, it doesn't enter into if block. What can cause this problem?

You can test through [this](https://www.codechef.com/ide) application quickly.

**Source**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    char lyric[] ="lorem ipsum is printing\nlorem ipsum is letters";
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, y = 0, l = 0, s = 0;

    s = sizeof(lyric)/sizeof(char);

    for(k; k<s; ++k)
    {
        if(lyric[k] == ' ')
            ++l;

        if(lyric[k] == '\n')
            ++l;
    }

    char *row;
    char *temp[l];

    row = strtok (lyric," \n");

    while (row != NULL)
    {
        temp[i++] = row;
        row = strtok (NULL, " \n");
    }

    for (i=0;i<l; ++i){
        for (j=(i+1);j<l; ++j){

            printf("%s == %s\n", temp[i], temp[j]);
            if(temp[i] == temp[j]){
                y++;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Unique word count : %d",y);

    return 0;
}
```

**Result**

```
lorem == ipsum
lorem == is
lorem == printing
lorem == lorem
lorem == ipsum
lorem == is
ipsum == is
ipsum == printing
ipsum == lorem
ipsum == ipsum
ipsum == is
is == printing
is == lorem
is == ipsum
is == is
printing == lorem
printing == ipsum
printing == is
lorem == ipsum
lorem == is
ipsum == is

Unique word count : 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code,

```
temp[i] == temp[j]
```

is not going to work *as expected* as the operands are pointers and what you want is to compare the contents of the memory pointed by the pointers, not the pointers themselves.

You need to use [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) to perform the comparisons.

Comment: Its not my intention to dishonor your answer, but how can you know that it isn't working as expected? I can't even extract from this OP, what he is expecting.

Comment: @Olaf edited to add a bit clarification, does it sound ok now?

Comment: @Zaibis well, I took reference of the previous printf statement and the o/p, that's all.

Comment: @Zaibis: Clairvoyance;-) Seriously: This is a typical beginners error (often because they don't read/understand the book properly or follow the lessons).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your comparison involves two pointers i.e. temp[i] and temp[j] are nothing but pointers pointing to a memory
What you need to compare is the value pointed by those pointers you can do that by dereferencing the pointers using asterisk (*) operator i.e 
(*temp[i]) and (*temp[j]) or if you do not want to do it manually then 
use strcmp as mentioned.
Refer this 
[C String -- Using Equality Operator == for comparing two strings for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933614/c-string-using-equality-operator-for-comparing-two-strings-for-equality)