# C-fgets() using stdin doesnt work

Tags: c, fgets

I'm trying to get input from `stdin`using `fgets` utilizing a character array with a size of 128 that is supposed to stop when it reads "exit" but it doesn't

```
char cmd[128];

if(fgets(cmd,128,stdin)=="exit"){
    //stuff
   }
```

Comment: tried using a printf("%s",cmd); using exit and it really prints exit without instead of terminating

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C String -- Using Equality Operator == for comparing two strings for equality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933614/c-string-using-equality-operator-for-comparing-two-strings-for-equality)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't compare strings with the `==` operator.

What you're actually doing here is comparing the function's return value (the address of `cmd` on success, `NULL` on failure) with the address of the string literal `"exit"`.  This will never be true.

You should check the return value for `NULL`, then use the `strcmp` function to compare `cmd` against `"exit"`:

```
if ((fgets(cmd,128,stdin)) != NULL && 
    (strcmp(cmd,"exit\n") == 0 || strcmp(cmd,"exit\r\n") == 0) {
    ...
```

Note that the `fgets` function stores a newline in the buffer if one is read, so we need to add that to the string to check.

Comment: Will `strcmp` go belly up in the event of `fgets` returning null?

Comment: Just to add to this, fgets will also read a newline into the buffer, so you need to use strncmp or add a newline to the string.

Comment: You'd need `strncmp` because the return from `fgets` would [probably] have a newline (i.e.) `exit\n` against `exit`, so it won't match as written

Comment: [If `fgets()` hits `EOF` without reading any input or fails it returns `NULL`.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) `strcmp(fgets(cmd,128,stdin),"exit")` is asking for `SIGSEGV`.

Comment: Good catch @EdHeal and others.  Edited.

Comment: @AndrewHenle i know i was just testing base case

Comment: `strncmp(cmd, "exit", 4)` will report a match on `"exitfoobar"` If you want to require the input to be exactly `"exit"`, then use `strcmp` to compare to `"exit\n"`. If you want to be more lax, you'll need to define exactly what qualifies as a match (`"Exit"`? `" exit "`?) and then write code to implement that.

Comment: How about the windows environment where `\n` will not suffice?

Comment: This should be _two_ `if` statements: `if (fgets(...) == NULL) break;` to handle EOF (otherwise, the loop won't terminate). Then, a newline strip with `strlen` or `strchr`, and then `if (strcmp(...))`

Comment: Edited to use `strcmp` instead of `strncmp`, and added checks for different newline styles.

Comment: @dbush - We got there eventually :-)