# inputting names on scanf

Tags: c, printf

I've been trying to make a small program for someone who is about to have their birthday and well, sadly I'm stuck in the first part, I insert

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char name[10];
    printf("Please enter your name. \n");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    if(name=='Mariana'){
        printf("Hello Onee-sama");
    }
    else if(name=='David'){
        printf("Im sure you're not my master");
    }
    else{
        printf("Sorry, you are not authorized");
    }
}
```

(I plead you ignore the abnormalities) and When i run it, whatever name I insert, it gives me the else response. I would really appreciate help :)

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings. This will save you time.

Comment: Too many errors. Follw @chux 's advice. And read [ask].

Comment: Your using single quotes for a const char[], use double quotes it will solve some of your problems. Also try using strcmp for string comparison

Comment: @AndreiTumbar 1) A string literal is immutable, but not `const` qualified (that would be C++). 2) The single-quotes are still a valid expression: an `int`. This (and other errors) will show up with a modern compiler and warnings enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The code KopKoder wrote works perfect. Just adding explanation as to why strcmp or strncmp has to be used and not '==' operator. C strings are actually char arrays or pointer to char, which means that comparing a pointer to a const array will always give unexpected results. The link below gives better explanation to your question.

[C String -- Using Equality Operator == for comparing two strings for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933614/c-string-using-equality-operator-for-comparing-two-strings-for-equality)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use strcmp to compare C char arrays. Here is your code modified.
Hope this helps!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char name[10];
    printf("Please enter your name. \n");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    if( (strcmp(name,"Mariana")) == 0){
        printf("Hello Onee-sama");
    }
    else if((strcmp(name,"David"))==0){
        printf("Im sure you're not my master");
    }
    else{
       printf("Sorry, you are not authorized");
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &name);` is as good as coding `gets()`.  Neither make for a quality answer.  `scanf("%9s", &name);` would be better .  `fgets()` then handling the `'\n'` would even be better.